# what is l2-ball, l1 penalty and optimization for sparseness in sparse filtering?

Tags: vector, filtering, sparse-matrix, feature-detection, iris-recognition

[image: Sparse filering]

All the information is given about the question. I am learning IRIS recognition and during this i got Sparse filtering.

Answer (score 2):

l2 ball -
suppose a vector x = 2x + 2y + 2z then l2 norm of this vector is square root of (sqr(2x) + sqr(2y) + sqr(2z)). Now when we find f(x) / (l2-norm of f(x)), this is equivalent to unit vector. Now, here f(x) is feature of one example, like-wise all features by this way lie on a sphere(circle if 2-D) of radius one. So, this is l2- ball.

Now Question is What is l1-penalty ? I hope, we will get it soon.